# Поиск шариков одинакового цвета

Tags: java

Пишу игру шарики. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как написать процедуру поиска шариков одинакового цвета и чтобы при нажатии на любой они все исчезали. Помогите, очень надо.

Comment: есть у кого нибудь хоть похожий код для образца

Answer (score 3):

Например так:

```
// this.всеШарики это HashMap<Integer, Шарик>
void ПоискШариковОдинаковогоЦвета(int Цвет){
    for (Integer i: this.всеШарики.keySet()){
        if (this.ВсеШарики.get(i).Цвет==Цвет) {
            this.ВсеШарики.remove(i);
        };
    };
};
```

Comment: Ой. Не заметил тэг java. Сейчас переделаю.

Comment: специфический псевдокод получился=)

Answer (score 2):

допустим, объекты "Шарик" `Spherule`(как подсказывает гугл-переводчик) имеет свойство `Color`, и метод `Disappear`, и где-то в другом объекте хранятся сслыки на все "шарики" в виде массива. Тогда:

```
public void Disappearance(string color)
{
    for(int i = SpherulesList.length-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        if(SpherulesList[i].Color.equals(color))
            SpherulesList[i].Disappear();
    }
}
```

Comment: В java можно именовать по-русски переменные :) Гугль зазря гоняли :)

Comment: в программировании нельзя именовать по-русски переменные!=)

Comment: В ответе на этот крайне хорошо сформулированный вопрос можно :)

Comment: спасибо разбираюсь!

Comment: Да, в программировании нельзя именовать переменные по русски, но проблема состоит в том, что люди это делают. С этим приходится считаться и жить.

Comment: "считаться и жить." - это поощрение ошибок и нарушений, по-моему за это надо наказывать

Comment: @Spectre, посмотрите [сюда][1] :) Я понимаю конечно, что это для поисковой оптимизации наверно сделано, но как забавно смотрится URL :)
[1]:http://hashcode.ru/users/?%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0=%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1

Comment: да, забавно

    http://hashcode.ru/users/?%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0=%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1

Comment: Chromium нормальный русский текст показывает....